# How can I create android apps that has a pre-loggedin feature?

Tags: android, unique

I want to design an android app for a website
The app will be downloaded through a unique link from my server
I want each user to download the app WITH HIS USERNAME LOGGED IN ALREADY FOR HIM

Is there a way to do that with an android app?

My aim is to let my users download an app and find themselves logged in without having to do it themselves

Comment: You want the login creds to be packaged with your app based on who downloaded it?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the app to be installed pre-aware of the credentials, you're going to have to have the website you're having them download the app from be wired up to compile a custom version of the package for each user.

Is it really that necessary for the user not to have to log in once and then have credentials remembered from that point on?